# Access a JSON inside a function: I get a type mismatch

Tags: json, vba, outlook-addin

If call a function which takes a Json (from the [VBA Json library](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON)) and some strings as inputs, I get a type mismatch.

If I access the Json from outside the function (with the original "json" object, not the function parameter "dataJson", it works.

Here is the code. I skip over some of the API Request logic as it works. I think the issue is related to passing a Json object to a function.

```vb
Public json As Object
    
Sub Main()
   'Some HTTP request logic
   Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(httpCall.responseText)
   someFunction json, "name", "id"
End Sub

Function someFunction(dataJson as Object, arg1 As String, arg2 As String)
    Debug.Print dataJson(1)(arg1)(arg2) 'this uses the VBA JSON library
    'As soon as I access items within dataJson, I get the type mismatch error
End Function
```

How can I access the json object inside the function?

There is the option of directly accessing the "json" variable which sits at the module-level (so I could use it inside the function), but that would be poor practice.

Comment: Difficult to make any suggestions without the JSON structure.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. I know it's simply not related to the JSON structure since running that exact `Debug.Print` statement outside the function works perfectly fine. I'm also unable to post specific data/code due to confidentiality concerns (apologies for that). The issue relates to accessing a JSON object from inside the function but I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: So if you put `Debug.Print json(1)(arg1)(arg2)` in `Main` it works?  Maybe try changing arg1 and 2 to Variant.

Comment: Yes. Basically, I used to get the JSON and put part of its content into UI elements, and repeat that like ten times (all in my Main sub). Using a function (to reduce redundancy of course) to access the same JSON is what created this issue. I've changed my argument types to Variant and the code seems to run (up until the next bug, that is). Thanks for the suggestion. It seems weird to me that a String object wouldn't be interpreted properly by VBA but I'm just a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the argument types from String to Variant seems to have squashed the bug. Thanks to Tim Williams for the suggestion.